# A condition for $\hat f$ to be integrable

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^1 (\mathbb R^n)$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous at zero and that the fourier transform $\hat f$ of $f$ is non-negative. Does this imply that $\hat f \in L^1$ (and hence, by the inversion theorem, that $f$ is continuous)? If so, how could I go about proving it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193114/a-positive-fourier-transform-is-integrable?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In [A positive "Fourier transform" is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193114/a-positive-fourier-transform-is-integrable?rq=1) Zarrax gave a great answer to this question using mollifiers. He/she also provides a counterexample in the case $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that $\hat f \in L^1$, but I think that you can get easily that $f$ is continuous.

If I remember right, $\hat{f}$ non-negative implies that $f$ is positive definite, and then Krein's inequality takes care of continuity...